# Making iOS 6 apps with an iOS 7 beta device

Tags: ios

This may seem an odd question but bear with me. I am all excited to try out iOS 7 beta, however I am developing an app that will be complete before iOS 7 comes out to the public.

So can I install iOS 7 on my device, and then develop and publish my app for iOS 6? Or would I need to downgrade to iOS 6 to develop my app and release it in the next few weeks?

I should add I want to do this because I only have one device.

Comment: If you are developing an app for iOS 6, why would you install iOS 7 on your development device? You need to test under iOS 6.

Comment: I only have one device, and my curiosity is strong

Comment: I recommend you not convert your device to iOS 7, as you won't be able to downgrade. In the event you need to test on an iOS 6 device you'll be left high and dry.

Comment: @thegrinner of course that you can downgrade, just put the device in recovery mode

Comment: if i release app for iOS 6 using xcode 4.6 can iOS 7 user access that app in iTunes?
My questions are block that why i have posted here.sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot release an app that has been built, compiled, or created with the pre-release SDKs and Tools. That means you can't release an app built with iOS 7 SDK features in Xcode 5 until Apple gives the green light for submission. (EDIT: iOS 7 is now public, but this will apply to any future betas - including iOS 7.1 and onward).

On the other hand, testing your app on a beta device is OK. It's **not a good idea** to test your iOS 6 app on iOS 7, but it will work. You can install iOS 7 beta on your device, but **first think about your users**. You'll want to test your app in the environment that your users will be using it in.

If you do upgrade to iOS 7 on your one and only device, you'll be stuck with the iOS Simulator - which is very very far from recommended. You can't downgrade or restore to an earlier iOS version from iOS 7.

Comment: You can actually downgrade by selecting the ios 6 firmware version in iTunes

Comment: @JomanJi You could, but that would cause baseband issues and may or may not work. As a result of baseband inconsistencies, you may or may not be able to upgrade later.

Comment: thanks for the info, I actually didn't know that, I guess I'll have to be more carefull!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the beta version of XCode, be sure to set the target to iOS 6, not iOS 7. When you target a version of iOS, that's the minimum version. You can run an app targeted for iOS 6 on iOS 7.

When you target iOS 6, the compiler will prevent you from including features that require iOS 7.

Still, for testing purposes, you'll want to test on a device with the latest released version. iOS 7 may have bug fixes that iOS 6 does not, so your app may run fine on iOS 7 but have bugs when run on iOS 6. Also, there may be performance differences.

You should test on both the simulator and an actual device, however if you want to risk it, the worst that will happen is your app may be rejected.

Comment: How to set the target to ios 6

Answer (score 0):

Theroretically you should not be able to run an app from Xcode 4 on an iOS 7 device. I was able to do this however, but I'm not sure why. Try deploying your app with Xcode 5 and then redeploy it with Xcode 4. In my case Xcode 4 would deploy to an iOS 7 device if the app is already installed (including all profiles).

Comment: Any app is forward compatible. As long as it runs smoothly, even apps from iOS 3 could run on iOS 7. That being said, it does not work the other way around - apps are only forward compatible, not backwards. I could even build an app with Xcode 3 and it would run fine on iOS 7.

Comment: Yes, but normally Xcode 4 would not allow you to deploy an app to an iOS 7 device. Try it (and if it works tell my why my Xcode 4 refuses to do so).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you there. You are correct that earlier versions of Xcode can't deploy to newer versions of iOS. I had forgotten about that - my bad. :)